# Z-index | need help for my website

Tags: css

i have a problem with the z-index in CSS.

code:

```
div.banniere{
    background-image:url('../img/banniere.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -23px 0;
    height: 750px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

p.menu-king{
    color: white;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
    z-index: 1;
}

div.menu-bar{
    background: black;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70px;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: -2;
    margin-top: 100px;
}


div.menu-bar > ul{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

li.menu{
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 64px;
}

li.menu > span{
    visibility: hidden;
}

li.menu:hover > span{
    visibility: visible;
}

li.menu:hover > span > a{
    background: black;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    display:inline;
}


img.menu-icon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    z-index: 1;
}


<div class="banniere"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar">
        <p class="menu-king">The king's offical website</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="menu"><img src="../img/1a.png" alt="home" class="menu-icon" /><span><a href="index.php?page=index">Accueil</a></span></li>
          <li class="menu"><img src="../img/2b.png" alt="home" class="menu-icon" /><span><a href="index.php?page=new">Actualité</a></span></li>
          <li class="menu"><img src="../img/2b.png" alt="home" class="menu-icon" /><span><a href="index.php?page=wof">WoF</a></span></li>
          <li class="menu"><img src="../img/2b.png" alt="home" class="menu-icon" /><span><a href="index.php?page=post-tester">POST-tester</a></span></li>
          <li class="menu"><img src="../img/2b.png" alt="home" class="menu-icon" /><span><a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact</a></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contenu">
```

I want:

- The div.banniere     -> position in Z: -1
- div.menu-bar         -> position in Z: -2
- div.menu-bar > ALL   -> position in Z: 1

But in my code it's doesn't work... Why ?

Thank you for your support !

Best regards, Bonvin Maxime.

Comment: can you put ur html code as well, better if u create a fiddle and share the exact problem

Comment: it depends much on your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

A lot depens n your html code. however, it's enough if you z-index and position the container items, you don't need to add z-index and position to all of the sub-elements of your container. Also I've seen that you've added z-index to p.menu-king, but that one misses the position property. Without a set position, z-index has no effect.
I suggest you add z-index only to the containers, and clean up your code.